# VSTS Error - AAD Tenant disconnection failed

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to disconnect VSTS Account from one AD Tenant to Another using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/disconnect-account-from-aad?view=vsts

Performed the following:

- Added Microsoft Account to VSTS
- Added Microsoft Account as Owner
- Gave this guest account in AzureAD Global Admin Rights and Owner Role on
  Subscription
- Logged in to VSTS and Azure Successfully

Attempted to Disconnect and received the following error:

```
AAD Tenant disconnection failed: AAD Tenant disconnection failed due to the error : Account entitlement not found in the dictionary for source identity 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.
```

Repeated with 3 different Microsoft Accounts - same issue. Cannot find any information on this error.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Patience is the answer! waited for 12 hours and the issue disappeared.